# How to meet required dependencies in order to install expect pecl extension on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, macports, expect, pecl

I am attempting to install the expect pecl extension.
OS version = 10.7.3
PHP version 5.3.10 installed via macports
expect version 5.45 installed via macports
The command I am executing:
`sudo pecl -d preferred_state=beta install expect`
fails with `ld: library not found for -lexpect`
The libexpect5.45.dylib file is located in /opt/local/lib
full output of the install command is here [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/KWHk7X0b)
From what I can tell pecl just can not find the libexpect library, I even tried prepending
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib/expect5.45` and
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/System/Library/Tcl/8.5/expect5.45` and
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib` each location has an expect5.45.dylib file.  It did not help.

Comment: @Robert Harvey <http://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey> Did you really have to simply close the question and down vote it ? How do I move it to a more appropriate site ? I recognized that the question might get more answers on a different site, but I didn't just want to duplicate it.  What is the correct protocol for doing that for future reference.  Thanks. Also I searched meta for instructions on how to move and I saw questions saying it was possible to do, but not explicit instructions on how to move a question.

Comment: Find the site you want to ask it on, and ask it there.  *Read their FAQ first.*